# Can't format USB, can't delete USB partition, through GUI, through terminal

Tags: usb, lubuntu, format

I can mount and unmount `/dev/sdb1` but when I try to format it, I cannot. Right now, even deleting the partition is taking 30 mins so far and even Gpart is not having any of it.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How did you create this USB?

Answer (score 0):

You MUST run `gparted` as `root`. From the command line, `/usr/bin/gparted-pkexec` will prompt you for your password, then start `gparted` as `root`, so it can write the raw device.